# JavaScript and CSS classes not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up a custom navigation bar which when I am scrolling through a website slides the current `nav` which is occupying the majority of the screen out slightly.

Example extracts from the CSS and JS are as follows

```
/*CSS*/
#topnav {
    top: 100px;
    background-color:white;
    border-top-style:solid;
}

.topActive {
    z-index:5000;
    width:3cm;
    background-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-right-style:none;
    color:white;
}

/*JS*/
if(nav == 0) {
    $("#topnav").addClass("topActive topnavb");
    ...
```

In this example, I would expect that when the nav tab in the nav bar slides out the background colour of it is black; however, in this case, the background colour would be white still. Essentially the `class` is not overriding the properties in the `id`

I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem

Comment: Just class wont override the properties by id.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Is there a different approach I could try?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on `specificity` which the other answers have been talking about I found a command which can be added to the end of the line. This is `!important`. Even though `!important` is normally considered bad practice, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/4601149) for more about the practice of using `!important`, in this case it is not considered bad practice. This is because it is overriding one property which is otherwise unchanged in any further use of style sheets in this website.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). From the link:

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> - Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> - ID selectors (e.g., #example).

So an `ID` will always override a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The css specificity of a class is lower than that of an id. This causes id rules to override class rules.

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score -1):

Browsers will choose the property that is defined in the more precise rule. Id selectors are more precise than class selectors. You juste have to use `#topnav.topActive` instead of `.topActive`

Comment: Better yet, reduce the specificity by using a different class for the base rules so the id isn't being used at all.